# Using With template tag in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code :

```
            {% for group in grouped_fields %}
            <tr>
                {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
                    {% with 'bgcolor2' as row_color %}
                {% else %}
                    {% with 'bgcolor1' as row_color %}
                {% endif %}
                
                {% for field in group %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">
                            <input maxlength="1" size="1" class="text-center bg-white">
                        </td>
                    {% else %}
                        {% if forloop.counter0|add:forloop.parentloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
                            {% with 'bgcolor2' as cell_color %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% with 'bgcolor1' as cell_color %}
                        {% endif %}
                        
                        <td class="w-11 text-center {{ cell_color }}">
                            <input class="text-center" size="4" placeholder="yy">
                            <br>
                            <span>xx</span>
                        </td>
                        
                        {% if forloop.last and forloop.parentloop.last %}
                            <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">اول</td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

that I copied from ChatGPT but it seems it does not include correct form of with.
There should be an {%endwith%} somewhere in the code so there wont be an error.
I cant figureout how to use the template tag correctly.

can someone aid me with this

Comment: I would advise not to use ChatGPT, at least not without having some basic understanding about the template language. ChatGPT is trained in "word mastery", it can talk very fluently about... nothing.

Comment: In this particular case, it simply misuses `with` completely: `with` is a short-lived variable definition, that thus has a very limited span, but ChatGPT uses it as some sort of assignment to a variable.

Comment: Please explain at least what this code should do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *don't* use ChatGPT as a device that writes your code. ChatGPT might automate some tasks, yes. But you need to at least understand what it is writing. Chatbots like ChatGPT might seem to have some intelligence, but these are just statistical word sequence generators.

As for the problem itself, it simply misues with as a way to assign a value to a variable, but that is not possible: a `{% with … %}` statement is used to assign a value to a variable for a limited scope.

Here we can use [**`{% cycle … %}`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) here:

```
{% for group in grouped_fields %}
  <tr>
    {% cycle 'bgcolor2' 'bgcolor1' as row_color silent %}
    {% for field in group %}
      {% cycle 'bgcolor2' 'bgcolor1' as cell_color silent %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">
          <input maxlength="1" size="1" class="text-center bg-white">
        </td>
      {% else %}
        <td class="w-11 text-center {{ cell_color }}">
          <input class="text-center" size="4" placeholder="yy">
          <br>
          <span>xx</span>
        </td>
        {% if forloop.last and forloop.parentloop.last %}
          <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">اول</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice and your answer
using your code fixes everything But it shows bunch of extra words at top of the table :
bgcolor2 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 bgcolor2 bgcolor1 ....

Comment: @Essiprog: yes, I forgot to add `silent`.